# Using bootstrap-multiselect with require.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, typeerror, bootstrap-multiselect

I want to use bootstrap-multiselect with require.js.
I added the following lines to the shim:

```
shim: {
bootstrap : {
            deps: [ 'jquery', 'jquery_ui']
        },
bootstrap_multiselect: {
            deps:['jquery', 'jquery_ui', 'bootstrap'],
            exports: 'multiselect'
        }
}
```

This is not working.
I am getting the following exception:

> "TypeError: $(...) multiselect is not a function"

on the following line-

> $('#SomeDiv').multiselect({

Does anyone know what to add in exports to make this work?

I also updated the bootstrap-multiselect file from this link:
https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/pull/665/files

I feel I am doing something wrong in the shim file.

Comment: I think you need not to mention exports here as there should be no global variable with name 'multiselect'.
Just wanted to know, can you please check your paths under require.config where you are pointing location of bootstrap_multiselect.js file?

Comment: Hi, the paths are correct, I found the answer though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve this error after I changed

```
define(['jquery'], function($){//multiselect js here}
```

to

```
define(['jquery', 'bootstrap_multiselect'], function($){//multiselect js here}
```

Comment: Hmm... yeah. You cannot use it if you don't load it.